# How can I put Jekyll content a multiple column layout?

Tags: jekyll

How can I put markup around specific sections within my markdown file? e.g. put divs around two lists and then another div around the rest of the content.

Using this as an example:

Markdown

```
* Eggs
* Flour
* Sugar

Text goes here
```

Output

```
<div class="section1">
<ul>
 <li>Eggs</li>
 <li>Flour</li>
 <li>Sugar</li>
</ul>

<div class="section2">
 <p>Text goes here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess you want something like this:

First, a "regular" layout file for the pages where you don't want to show ingredients and preparation:

### `/_layouts/default.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

{{ content }}

</body>
</html>
```

Nothing special here, just a very basic layout file.

---

Then, a second layout file for the pages where you actually want to show recipes:
*(I'll call it "recipes", because "ingredients" and "preparation" sounds like you're building a site about cooking)*

### `/_layouts/recipe.html` :

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="ingredients">
    <ul>
    {% for item in page.ingredients %}
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="preparation">
{{ content }}
</div>
```

---

Now you can create pages like this, where you put the list of ingredients into the YAML front-matter and the preparation in the content:

```
---
layout: recipe
title: Cake recipe
ingredients:
  - name: sugar
  - name: milk
  - name: eggs
---

Here's the "how to prepare the cake" text
```

---

This will generate the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cake recipe</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Cake recipe</h1>

<div class="ingredients">
    <ul>
        <li>sugar</li>
        <li>milk</li>
        <li>eggs</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="preparation">
Here's the "how to prepare the cake" text
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

## EDIT:

Concerning your question:

> I'm not sure though if it will work as I need to format the ingredients list with some bolding, e.g.:100ml **water** and I don't think I can do this in YAML?

You could separate the ingredient and the amount in the front-matter of the page:

```
---
layout: recipe
title: Cake recipe
ingredients:
  - name: sugar
    amount: 1 pound
  - name: milk
    amount: 100ml
  - name: eggs
    amount: 3
---

Here's the "how to prepare the cake" text
```

And the new layout file `/_layouts/recipe.html`:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="ingredients">
    <ul>
    {% for item in page.ingredients %}
        <li>{{item.amount}} <b>{{item.name}}</b></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="preparation">
{{ content }}
</div>
```

The generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cake recipe</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Cake recipe</h1>

<div class="ingredients">
    <ul>
        <li>1 pound <b>sugar</b></li>
        <li>100ml <b>milk</b></li>
        <li>3 <b>eggs</b></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="preparation">
Here's the "how to prepare the cake" text
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I'm not sure though if it will work as I need to format the ingredients list with some bolding, e.g.:100ml **water** and I don't think I can do this in YAML?